# Push object including key into array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array and object which look like this:

```
const myArray = [];

_meta: {
    pageContext: {
        pageType: "Homepage",
        label: "pageContext"
    }
}
```

and I want to push the object pageContext including it's key into an array. How do I do that? If i do:

```
myArray.push(model._meta.pageContext);
```

I get only the contents of page context in my array. I want the result to be like:

```
[
    pageContext: {
        pageType: "Homepage",
        label: "pageContext"
    }
]
```

Is there fancypants es6 trickery to do this?

Comment: Are you not getting any syntax errors? Especially for the first example...?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

have u seen this ?

Comment: You could just assign directly to the "key" you want... `myArray.pageContext = model._meta.pageContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can contain `objects` and not keys, Your expected output is an invalid object

Your array can look like

```
[{
    pageContext: {
        pageType: "Homepage",
        label: "pageContext"
    }
}]
```

by doing

```
myArray.push(model._meta);
```

Comment: yes, that's what i'm looking for. Unfortunately there's a lot in meta I don't need but i'll just have to delete that after adding _meta object.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the result to be like

What you've shown after that is invalid (well, okay, you *could* create something like that, but it's generally a bad idea*). You can create this, though:

```
[
    {
        pageContext: {
            pageType: "Homepage",
            label: "pageContext"
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the array contains an object, which contains `pageContext`.

If that's the result you want, and if `_meta` is really as shown, just push `_meta`:

```
myArray.push(model._meta);
```

Example:

```js
const myArray = [];

const model = {
  _meta: {
      pageContext: {
          pageType: "Homepage",
          label: "pageContext"
      }
  }
};

myArray.push(model._meta);
console.log(myArray);
```

If `_meta` has other things in it that you don't want to push, create a new object:

```
myArray.push({pageContext: model._meta.pageContext});
```

Example:

```js
const myArray = [];

const model = {
  _meta: {
      pageContext: {
          pageType: "Homepage",
          label: "pageContext"
      },
      somethingElse: {
           weDontWant: "this"
      }
  }
};

myArray.push({pageContext: model._meta.pageContext});
console.log(myArray);
```

---

* If you **really** want to have an array with a `pageContext` property on it, you can do that, because arrays are objects:

```
myArray.pageContext = model._meta.pageContext;
```

But most of the time, if you think you want to do that, you don't want an array at all, you just want a non-array object.

Answer (score 0):

But what you want is invalid JS. You could obtain something like

```
[
    { 
        pageContext: {
            pageType: "Homepage",
            label: "pageContext"
        }
    }
]
```

by using

```
myArray.push(model._meta);
```

or something like

```
[
    { 
        name: 'pageContext',
        value: {
            pageType: "Homepage",
            label: "pageContext"
        }
    }
]
```

by using

```
myArray.push({ name: 'pageContext', value: model._meta.pageContext });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {
        pageType: "Homepage",
        label: "pageContext"
    }
]
```

**If you already know that each object is pageContext then push**

```
myArray.push(model._meta.pageContext);
```